# Can you combine Javascript into single file without minifying it with yui-compressor?

Tags: javascript, yui-compressor

Is there a way to compress input javascript in a sinlge file but not minify it using Yui-Compressor?

```
  string compressedJavascript = JavaScriptCompressor.Compress(uncompressedJavascript)
```

This what I have now. I see the Compress() is overloaded to allow code to be left obfuscated, etc. But I would like the code to be left unminified for debugging.

Comment: if I understand well, you just want to concatenate several JS files ? If so, it's just a matter of reading all files sequentially and appending the data into another one.

Comment: Yep.. and Im wondering if the yui-compressor does that already. I believe SquishIt does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems YUI's [command line documentation](https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/blob/master/doc/README) says to use the `-nomunge` option which means:

> Minify only. Do not obfuscate local symbols.

Look for that in the documentation for the C# port you are using.

Comment: I think the OP wants to avoid minification entirely.